# Know the length of an input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

how to know the length of an input in Javascript

```
alert("Size: "+document.getElementById('champ').length)
```

> not work undefined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
alert("Size: "+document.getElementById('champ').value.length)
```

You have to pluck the "value" attribute from the DOM element, and get the length of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' id='champ' length=3 value="ab">

document.getElementById("champ").getAttribute("length")
//returns 3

document.getElementById("champ").value.length
//returns 2
```